# HTML - Accessing div in document exactly by position in one go

Tags: javascript, html, yii

I have a page generated by `Yii CListView` which contains a `div` and`multiple child divs`.I need to access a specific the child `div` and add one more `div` into that.

Although I managed to solve it using one approach but dont think its the right one. Following is the overview of my solution (*the code below does not contain all necessary variables declarations and other stuff, I have pasted the core code not the complete.*):

1. Accessed the parent div by Id (Since the Id was available as I can
   code this into Yii)
2. Obtained all the elements in this div using  :

   ```
   var div_childern = document.getElementById('StudentGridViewId').getElementsByTagName('*');
   ```
3. Iterated through and when reached to the desired div, added my new div. Please note that the div in which I want to add new div has the class name as "items". Code as below:

   ```
       for (var i = 0; i < div_childern.length; i++) {
       if (div_childern[i].getAttribute('class')=='items'){
           document.getElementById('StudentGridViewId').getElementsByTagName('*')[i].appendChild(newdiv);
           i=div_childern.length+1;
       }
     }
   ```

The only problem in this solution is, I am accessing the whole document twice, the call to  `getElementsByTagName`. First to obtain the list of all `items` and then again to add my new `div`. Is there a better way to this ?

and also, could anyone point me to set the `Id` of the "items" `div` that `Yii` generates?

Thanks
Faisal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get a much more elegant solution if you use JQuery.
But, if you want to use the traditional javascript, here is what you could do

```
  for (var i = 0; i < div_childern.length; i++) {
    if (div_childern[i].getAttribute('class')=='items'){
        div_childern[i].appendChild(newdiv);
        i=div_childern.length+1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Here is jQuery version as Divya suggested. This is much more elegant and neat.                       $('#StudentGridViewId').find('.items').prepend(newdiv);